# bigdecimal dependency -- how to declare in gemspec

Tags: ruby

In my Ruby file, I require the following:

```
require 'bigdecimal'
require 'bigdecimal/util'
```

I am unsure as to how to declare dependencies in my gemspec file.
Here is what I have, and it doesn't seem to be working:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency    "bigdecimal", ["=1.2.5"]
s.add_runtime_dependency    "bigdecimal/util"
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `bigdecimal` is part of ruby std-lib so you don't need to add any dependency

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your gemspec file you are declaring dependencies to other gems that you can find on rubygems.org.

something like this:

```
s.add_runtime_dependency('crack', '>= 0.3')
```

the gemspec is not responsible for loading dependencies "at runtime" it's just the naming in contrast to `add_development_dependency` which are used during development time of the gem.

as @bijhaid already stated, bigdecimal is part of the ruby standard library and does not need to be declared in the gemspec in any way.

you just require it in your code before you use it.

Comment: @user3417719 saying thanks is very polite! the way of saying thx to people on stackoverflow is upvoting and accepting answers.